# Can we pass data form view composer to view rendered from controller

Tags: laravel

I am pass some data from view composer to view and it works fine, but when i tried to pass same data to views rendered from controller it gives variable undefined error. Any suggestion would be help-full.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for the composer and the controller function?

Comment: May be some variable, other than that you talking about, that you forgetto pass for example ! to help us can you add some code :)

Comment: Given the details of your question, the answer is : There is something wrong. Fix it.

Comment: I got the answer it had not mentioned view name is composer file.

Answer (score 0):

View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.
 If we don't mention the name of view in view composer e.g.

```
View::composer(
['profile', 'dashboard'],
'App\Http\ViewComposers\MyViewComposer'
```

);

and try to use variable passed to view composer will give "variable undefined error".
[View Composers]